# How to iterate through an array of listed elements completing a set of actions each time

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I have an array of a table grid of elements that each link to a record, I would like to list the elements and then create an instruction block, each time the test will select i+0 and iterate till it reaches the end of the array

I have already created the array and am able to printout the list of .text from the elements, however i cannot get it to iterate through the array without typing the instruction block each time and writing the click event from the page with i+0 -*.

```
List<WebElement> allRecords = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'gridBodyTable_primaryField')]"));
        List<String> all_elements = new ArrayList<>();
        int i; for (i = 0; i < allRecords.size(); i++) {
            all_elements.add(allRecords.get(i).getText());
            allRecords.get(i).click();
            exitiframe();
            enteriframe("contentIFrame1");
            elementPresentFail(By.cssSelector("[id$=fieldChangeIndicatorImage]"));
            exitiframe();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Tabnav_accts-main")).click();
            enteriframe("contentIFrame0");
            allRecords.get(i+1).click();
            exitiframe();
            enteriframe("contentIFrame1");
            elementPresentFail(By.cssSelector("[id$=fieldChangeIndicatorImage]"));
            exitiframe();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Tabnav_accts-main")).click();
            enteriframe("contentIFrame0");
            allRecords.get(i+2).click();
            exitiframe();
            enteriframe("contentIFrame1");
            elementPresentFail(By.cssSelector("[id$=fieldChangeIndicatorImage]"));
            exitiframe();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Tabnav_accts-main")).click();
        }
```

I would like to be able to list the elements located in the grid from the xpath "contains" then select them in order, complete an action, provided in on the same page, select the next listed record until the end of the list.

Currently I have to copy the action block out over again and again, if this could be more logical and a bit more compact would be better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the below approach. This will make sure the loop works for all the elements and also you don't get the StaleElementException.

```
int recordsCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'gridBodyTable_primaryField')]")).size();
for (int i = 0; i < recordsCount; i++) {
    allRecords = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'gridBodyTable_primaryField')]"));
    all_elements.add(allRecords.get(i).getText());
    allRecords.get(i).click();
    exitiframe();
    enteriframe("contentIFrame1");
    elementPresentFail(By.cssSelector("[id$=fieldChangeIndicatorImage]"));
    exitiframe();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Tabnav_accts-main")).click();
    enteriframe("contentIFrame0");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and good morning, I will surely give this a try today!

Comment: That works almost perfectly thank you, so much more elegant and less cluttering!

Comment: Would I be able to ask a favour, could you explain how you managed to make this, I am grateful you helped but i would also like to know how for future rather than copy paste. @supputuri